# File upload error in flask

Tags: file-upload, flask

```
@app.route('/registerdriver', methods=['POST'])
def register_driver():
    fname = request.form['fname']
    lname = request.form['lname']
    email = request.form['email']
    mobno = request.form['mobno']
    password = request.form['password']

    file = request.files['driving_license']
    file.filename = mobno+"_"+fname

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Above is the code I used for saving the file. However the following error pops out while trying to save the file

> flask.debughelpers.DebugFilesKeyError
>
> flask.debughelpers.DebugFilesKeyError: You tried to access the file
>   "driving_license" in the request.files dictionary but it does not
>   exist.  The mimetype for the request is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "multipart/form-data"
>   which means that no file contents were transmitted.  To fix this error
>   you should provide enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

The browser instead transmitted some file names.

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Can you show me your html `form`?

Comment: Simply include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your <form> tag.

Comment: Being a beginner i forgot that :P

Answer (score 9):

In your html form tag include

```
<form action="/path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Comment: even after providing enctype="multipart/form-data" I get the same error