# How to save an image into a folder inside the static folder using HTML form input type file and flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

In my flask app I want the user to be able to upload an image to a folder inside the static folder - called wallpaper. Currently I'm receiving a *flask.debughelpers.DebugFilesKeyError*, however I don't see any error in the keys I'm using

---

### What I've tried

---

**flaskapp.py**

```
@app.route('/changeWallpaper' , methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def change_home_wallpaper():

    UPLOADS_PATH = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static\\wallpaper')

    if request.method == "POST":
        wallpaper = request.files['wallpaper']
        if wallpaper.filename != '':
                image = request.files['wallpaper']
                image.save(os.path.join(UPLOADS_PATH, secure_filename(image.filename)))

        cur = db2.cursor()
        sql = f"UPDATE wallpaper set pic = {wallpaper.filename} where sno = 1"
        cur.execute(sql)
        db2.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**loggedin.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="{{url_for('change_home_wallpaper')}}" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <input type="file" name="wallpaper"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559035/8843270, this might give you some clues

Comment: @simkus Thanks I had to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`,  and  put `{wallpaper.filename}` in quotes. Do you mind adding it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `HTML`

```html
<form action="/path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

and put `{wallpaper.filename}` in quotes.